# Reading text from TIFF scans

Tags: text, tiff

I have ca 1,200 scans of C19th prints. Each print has the original publication data (artist, title, publisher's address, date etc) printed (usually) below the picture of the print.  The scans are high resolution TIFF files, each typically 0.5-1.7 GB. The cataloguing project requires that this metadata is captured so that different publications can be searched for.

I have been reading the publication text from the screen and retyping into a matching database.
Is there any way to pick and OCR this text, then paste into the relevant database fields?  The data is too variable for this process to be automated, but OCR should cut down the time needed a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it's possible if you have OCR software which allows you to make a small selection of an image on-screen.

If you are looking for software for Windows, [ShareX](https://getsharex.com/) is free, and has Text Capture (OCR) function. Basically it scans the selected area, and produces a text file. From there you can copy and paste.

Here's a screenshot showing the functionality.

[image]

Note: I have no affiliation with ShareX. There are probably other similar applications available.